# Stackoverflow ripped off?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Looks like the clone wars have begun :(
http://www.excbadaccess.com

This isn't running on the so-engine right?
If it is then that's cool otherwise...booooooooo

Comment: according to the FAQ, it is iPhone specific http://www.excbadaccess.com/faq

Comment: Ah, cool.  I searched for it on here but I didn't see it right away. I will look harder next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites

There it is listed. So running officially on stackoverflow I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Old news:
[Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/so-clones)

Also, this is a StackExchange site, not a clone:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites

Answer (score 0):

This is a [stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/) website - using the same engine as SO, SU, SF and MSO.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites) is a list of (most) stackexchange websites.